# Scala higher kinded type syntax

Tags: scala, generics, types, higher-kinded-types

I'm new to Scala and new to higher kinded types.  I want to write something like this;

```
trait Actor[E[Dependency] <: Event[Dependency]] {
  def execute(dependency: Dependency): Unit
}
```

However I can't refer to the type parameter Dependency in the execute method - the compiler doesn't know it.

I'm aware I can solve it in the following way without HKTs, but this isn't what this question is about;

```
trait Actor[T <: Event[Dependency], Dependency] {
   def execute(dependency: Dependency): Unit
}
```

I'd like to understand why it doesn't work with the higher kinded type syntax that I've tried?  Is it possible at all to express this with HKTs?  Is this a valid use-case for a HKT?

---

***EDIT***

A bit more information, Event looks like this;

```
trait Event[Data] {
   val payload: Data
}
```

...and I'm looking to define an event and an actor like this;

```
case class FooEvent(payload: Foo) extends Event[Foo]

class FooActor extends Actor[FooEvent] {
   def execute(dependency: Foo) = {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to improve Alexey's answer - he is right, but he is too short. But I must say that I'm not an expert in HKT and I think I'm only starting to understand the concept.

In your code `E[Dependency]` is the same as `E[_]` which says that you have `E` with some type as parameter. This means that you do not operate over `Dependency` as type. You also do not operate over `E` or `E[Dependency]` as the type either. `E` is a type constructor, and `E[Dependency]` is an existential type if I understood it correctly. Please note that

```
trait Actor[E[D] <: Event[D]] { def execute(d: E) {} }
```

or

```
trait Actor[E[D] <: Event[D]] { def execute(d: E[D]) {} }
```

won't compile either.

You need to specify the proper type as an argument for execute:

```
trait Actor[E[D] <: Event[D]] { def execute[B](d: E[B]) {} }
```

This one will compile as `E[B]` is the type in this context.

**Updated:**

Please take a look at this code:

```
  trait Event[P] {
    val payload: P
  }

  case class FooEvent(payload: Int) extends Event[Int]

  trait BaseActor {
    type E = Event[P]
    type P
    def execute(dep: P)
    def runEvent(event: E)
  }

  trait IntActor extends BaseActor {
    type P = Int
  }

  class FooActor extends IntActor {
    def execute(dependency: P) = {}
    def runEvent(event: E) = {}
  }

  val c = new FooActor()
  c.runEvent(FooEvent(5))
  c.execute(5)
```

Basically the trick is to define `type P` which is our `Dependency` and `type E = Event[P]` which is always `Event[Dependency]` then you can use the actor by defining `P` without defining `E` as it is already defined. Not sure whether it solves the issue, but it looks like a way to go to me. There are also too many types here, some like `IntActor` is not necessary. I've put them so it is easier to understand the example

Comment: This is useful, but just to clarify: there are no existential types involved, despite the similar syntax.

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but I think your first example does in fact compile. Think I did it that way briefly yesterday.

Comment: Your last example is interesting but doesn't really solve my problem as the type parameters on the method definition have no relationship with those on the trait.

Comment: @RyanWorsley I don't think your case is something were you need to use HKT. You need to define your `Dependency` as a type, to be able to specify it. The exact stuff you want is logically impossible, see Alexey's example. You cannot create an `Actor` instance without specifying the `Data` type, because `Actor` is dependant on `Data`

Comment: You're right that I don't need to, in fact I show how to do it without HKTs in my original question. The reason I'm going down this road is because it seems to me that the compiler has enough information for me to capture and use the type Dependency. This makes for an overall nicer syntax because I only need to specify a single type parameter to Actor, rather than two. If you think about it, the definition of FooActor tells the compiler the type of Dependency, so what I thought was that HKTs are almost like pattern matching for types, where I can decompose the type structure and use the parts.

Comment: Either I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the point of HKTs or it's just a limitation of the compiler. My questions are here to help my clarify that, unfortunately I'm not there yet!

Comment: @RyanWorsley HKTs simply don't work like this at all, and aren't intended to work like this.

Comment: I've actually gone with a hybrid of both answers and now think I understand the purpose of HKTs better.  I've selected Archeg as I feel there's more information there for anyone who comes along and reads this later.  Thanks both of your for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> However I can't refer to the type parameter Dependency in the execute method - the compiler doesn't know it.

You can't because it *isn't* a parameter of `Actor`. Consider

```
val actor = new Actor[Event] // E is Event
actor.execute(???) // what argument is this supposed to take? I.e. what is Dependency for Actor[Event]?
```

UPDATE: Given your edit, the `[Dependency, T <: Event[Dependency]]` option is *precisely* what you need. When you write `Actor[E[Dependency] <: Event[Dependency]]`, this means `E` itself has to have a type parameter. And `FooEvent` doesn't, so `Actor[FooEvent]` won't compile.

UPDATE 2: You could try using type members as follows:

```
trait Event {
  type Dependency
  val payload: Dependency
}

trait Actor {
  type E <: Event

  def execute(e: E#Dependency)
}

class Foo

case class FooEvent(payload: Foo) extends Event {
  type Dependency = Foo
}

class FooActor extends Actor {
  type E = FooEvent

  def execute(e: Foo) = {}
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow your argument, so I've added some more detail that should show you what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So what I'm actually saying is, Actor depends on some type which itself depends on another type. There's no way for me to then define the method execute as taking type Dependency? Is this just a limitation of compiler or is it something fundamentally not possible?

Comment: I've actually gone with a hybrid of both answers and now think I understand the purpose of HKTs better.  I've selected Archeg as I feel there's more information there for anyone who comes along and reads this later.  Thanks both of your for your help.